# Check unused cucumber step definitions

Tags: webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I am using webdriverio with cucumber and would like to clear my project from unused step definitions and code. I tried to use this "cucumber-js --dry-run --format usage" but I received "No step definitions" as a result. Can someone tell me do I have to add some additional parameter, some configuration or sth. else. Or is other way to do this? Or maybe there is some appropriate tool or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

it could be that inside your Cucumber config you are not pointing to the `step-definitions` folder. Here is my config, notice the `require` pointing to `step-definitions` folder and `paths` pointing to `features` folder:

```
/**
 * @exports Cucumber default config
 */
export default {
    paths: ['src/features/**/*.feature'],
    parallel: 2,
    requireModule: ['ts-node/register'],
    require: ['src/step-definitions/**/*.ts'],
    strict: true,
    format: ['json:reports/cucumber-report.json', 'progress'],
    formatOptions: {
        snippetInterface: 'async-await'
    }
};
```

Then here are the scripts that I'm using for checking undefined and steps usage, they are located inside my `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
  "features:usage": "cucumber-js src/features/ --format usage --dry-run",
  "features:undefined": "cucumber-js src/features/ --format snippets --dry-run"
 }
```

`features:usage` logs in which `.steps` file step has been defined as well as in which `.feature` file(s) the steps is being used.

`features:undefined` logs undefined steps in this format:

```
Then('Random step', async function () {
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  return 'pending';
});
```

I'm using `npm` so I'm running them like `npm run features:usage`, for example.

References:

1. [cucumber-js-docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/snippets.md)
2. [cucumber-playwright-template-repo](https://github.com/Tallyb/cucumber-playwright?tab=readme-ov-file)